# Macincloud ctrl and drag alternative for xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm trying to create an iOS app by using Macincloud but here's my problem. I'm trying to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag to set a new root controller in the storyboard but Macincloud wont allow you to do this. Instead it just moves the NavigationView around the screen.

Does anyone have a solution to this or at least an alternative way of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the MacInCloud website shortly after you posted this question:

Problem: When using MacinCloud, the Ctrl+Drag operation does not work properly.

Cause: This is a common issue associated with controlling the Mac through a remote client software such as Remote Desktop Connection. Please see the solution for the current workaround.

Workaround:

1. Move a Controller in Interface Builder
   Double-clicking the object in the side bar
   Move it using the arrow keys
2. Use Interface Builder to connect a view element to file owner 
   Right-clicking the element
   The popup appears, drag the circle on the right hand side of the property to what you want to link to
3. Connect two controls in Main Space or Document Outlines (left pane)
   Point to the Target Control
   RightClick to open context menu with available Connection points
   Select a Connection circle at the left side of menu, circle becames a "+"
   Click the "+" sign and drag it to the Source Control
   Release mouse to create new connection
4. Create and connect new outlet (Assistant Editor mode)
   Create a New Outlet manually in the Assistant Editor pane
   Point to the New Outlet in Connection Inspector (right pane)
   Select the New Outlet circle at the left side of Connection Inspector, circle becames a "+"
   Click the "+" sign and drag it to the Source Control in the IB

Cite:
https://support.macincloud.com/support/solutions/articles/8000007774-alternative-method-to-ctrl-drag-control-drag-